# How to reference a field value on a page in SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I know I can do this from code behind (I'm using VB), but I would think I should be able to do this in the ASP:sqldatasource.

All I want to do is select records where the value of field in the table is equal to the value of a hidden field on the page.

On selected node change of a tree view I set the value of a hidden field named: NLHF. I use this elsewhere so I know it works as expected (setting this value). The issue is I want to reference this value in a SQL select statement and I am failing miserably.

The code in question is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SupervisorSQLDS" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ myconnectionstring %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ContactID, DisplayName AS ListItem FROM Contact WHERE LocationID = NLHF ORDER BY ListItem">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I believe this is just the syntax... feeling not so bright but I giving up after a couple of hours of looking and trying different things.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I guess if I was not clear... LocationID is a field in the table and NLHF is the hidden field I set on selectednodechanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parameters to your query, so the SQL becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ContactID, DisplayName AS ListItem 
FROM Contact 
WHERE LocationID = @NLHF 
ORDER BY ListItem
```

Then bind a [ControlParameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx) to your datasource's select command

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SupervisorSQLDS" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ myconnectionstring %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT ContactID, DisplayName AS ListItem FROM Contact WHERE LocationID = @NLHF ORDER BY ListItem">

  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="NLHF" ControlID="NLHF" PropertyName="Value"/>
  </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone else who is looking at this for help... be aware the property name will matter. In my case it was different; don't let that trip you up too much.

Comment: I have changed it to Value, is that what you used to get it to work?

Comment: Yes... but as it turns out I unexpectedly left the office. I thought it was good because the error stopped and the page loaded. But, I just now discovered the problem is not fully resolved. When I click on a node ion the treeview I get the exception:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@NLHF". I am working on this now. There is nothing that references this at all other than the code in the page file which is as you have edited above.

Comment: Got it... this:  ControlParameter Name="@NLHF"   should be like this:   ControlParameter Name="NLHF"